# Изменяемый SELECT WHERE statement при нажатии на элемент

Tags: php, mysql

Есть два файла, index.php и open.php. Первый сама страница, второй содержит сам SELECT. Причина почему так: для тестирования в документах. Если что-то написано некорректно или не правильно, заранее извиняюсь.

Куски кода:

```html
  <div class="part">
  <div class="content">
  <a href="open.php"><img src="pic/example.png"/></a>
  Name1
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <a href=""><img src="pic/example.png"/></a>
  Name2
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <a href=""><img src="pic/example.png"/></a>
  Name3
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <a href=""><img src="pic/example.png"/></a>
  Name4
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <a href=""><img src="pic/example.png"/></a>
  Name5
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
      <?php
      require("connect.php");

      try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
      }
      catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
      }

      $data = $pdo->query('SELECT *
                           FROM Partners 
                           WHERE NAME="Name" 
                           AND STAR="2" 
                           AND COLOR="Red"');
      while ($oneRow = $data->fetch()){
      echo '<br/>'.'Name: '.$oneRow['NAME'].'<br/>'.'Star:'.$oneRow['STAR'].
      '<br/>'.'Level: '.$oneRow['LEVEL'].'<br/>'.'Color: '.$oneRow['COLOR'];
      }
      ?>
```

Интересует одно, как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на картинку срабатывал бы SELECT, но при этом под определённое нажатие. 
Например: Происходит нажатие на картинку с подписью name2, срабатывает SELECT, но при этом в нём меняется WHERE NAME="Name" на NAME="Name2". Возможно ли это? Если да, то возможно ли это без JS?

Я не слишком силён в программировании, поэтому мой подход возможно и не правилен, если так, буду благодарен за любую помощь :)

Comment: Можно обернуть каждую картинку в форму, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: Что значит "срабатывал", что должно измениться на экране после получения данных ? Если например переход на новую страницу в которой будет все о Name2, то вам надо при вызове передать в запросе пераметр вроде `<a href='test.php?name=Name2'>` а в php коде соответственно использовать этото параметр из `$_GET['name']` и запрос в БД оформлять как вот тут http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php в примере 2. Если же страница перегружаться не должна то делать примерно то же самое через ajax

Comment: @Mike Под "срабатыванием" я имел его запуск, действие, возможно есть какое либо более точное определение, но я его к сожалению не знаю. Хотелось бы так-же уточнить, как между собой связывать $_GET и запрос в бд? Никак не могу взять в толк.

Comment: Связать просто `$sth=$dbo->prepare('select * from .... where NAME=? ...'); $sth->execute(array($_GET['name']));`  http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю если без JS, то можно в каждую ссылку засунуть путь на open.php с GET параметрами вида `<a href="yoursite.com/open.php?docName=Name">` и в open.php проверять $_GET['docName']. Далее эту переменную подставлять в запрос. На забываем, что переменную нужно хотя бы прокинуть через плейсхолдеры (http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Что тут подразумевается под "docName"? Не совсем понял этот момент.

Comment: в строке, после ? передаются пары ключь - значение, на серверной стороне, значиение Name  будед доступно по ключу docName - $_GET['docName']